# How to reduce height and size of Material-UI<Select> input field in Material UI & formik?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, formik, formik-material-ui

I am making a web project using [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Material](https://next.material-ui.com/), [Formik](https://formik.org/), [formik-material-ui](https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui).

This is the input screen I am getting of my form. The select input height is bigger than the textfield inputs.

[image]

The InputField component is as follows:

```
import { Field } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";

const TextFieldStyle = {
    padding: 7,
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
};

export default (props: any) => {
    return (
        <Field
            component={TextField}
            inputProps={{
                style: TextFieldStyle,
            }}
            size="small"
            margin="none"
            variant="outlined"
            {...props} // add props at the key to override any user defined similar props
        >
            {props.children}
        </Field>
    );
};
```

The Select Field component is as follows:

```
import { Field } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";

const SelectFieldStyle = {
    padding: 7,
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
};

export default (props: any) => {
    return (
        <Field
            component={TextField}
            inputProps={{
                style: SelectFieldStyle,
            }}
            type="text"
            select={true}
            align="left"
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            margin="none"
            variant="outlined"
            {...props} // add props at the key to override any user defined similar props
        >
              <MenuItem value={1}>A</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>B</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>C</MenuItem>
        </Field>
    );
};
```

Changing the style in Select component is not bringing any visual change.

How can I bring the select component to the same height as input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SelectProps on your Select field thusly:

```
import { Field } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";

const SelectFieldStyle = {
    padding: 7,
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
};

export default (props: any) => {
    return (
        <Field
            component={TextField}
            SelectProps={{
                style: SelectFieldStyle,
            }}
            type="text"
            select={true}
            align="left"
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            margin="none"
            variant="outlined"
            {...props} // add props at the key to override any user defined similar props
        >
              <MenuItem value={1}>A</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>B</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>C</MenuItem>
        </Field>
    );
};
```

Here's the link to the API: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/